# EditText never has value

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a pretty basic EditText that I pull data from as a double via a button. 
It's value does not appear to change - if I use `android:text="2"`, and pull the value, it comes up as 2. But if I leave it blank, type in it, and try to pull the value, it comes up blank or null.

**The Problem:** (since I suppose it hasn't been clear enough) when I launch my app, type "3" into the EditText, and press my button that calls `String b = input.getText().toString();` and outputs `b` in a Toast and mathematical equation, it is blank and the equation calls an invalid input (my try/catch). The EditText supposedly never has a value.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:hint="-->"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

...
Spinner spinner1, spinner2; //class space
    EditText res, input;
    Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_math);

        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.unit_a);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unit_b);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
...

    public void convert(View view) {
        int operation = 0;
        double cm = 0;
        String a;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.input.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(operation == 0) {
                //CM TO IN
            try {
                cm = Double.parseDouble(MainActivity.this.input.getEditableText().toString());
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid input! (" + MainActivity.this.input.getText().toString() + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            a = Double.toString(cmToIn(cm));
            res.setText(a + "dfsdf", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //same as below
        }else if(operation == 1) {
            //etc.
        }else {
            res.setText("Something went wrong! :("); //temp, completely dysfunctional
        }
    }
```

Edit: I apologize, the Toast I had for a while was incorrect because I managed to Ctrl + Z back to a dumb mistake before copying. Sorry. Fixed. Problem still occuring though.

Comment: And I know it's not exactly "okay" to ask this, but if you could try to explain why you would downvote when/before downvoting, that would be nice. One downvote will get me question-banned again and I really need this project done. Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Please update your question with right information.

Comment: You could use `input.getText()` if you just looking at retrieving the content in the `editText`. And also I notice that `android:layout_width=0dp` change it to `10dp` or more

Comment: zIronManBox I said clearly in the title AND THE QUESTION that it wasn't updating as you typed, so the value was always the value at the launch of the app. 
That's what I'm doing, but parsing it to a double. Pay attention.
I'm using weights, and lots and lots of people say to have the width at 0dp when using weights to avoid distortion.

Comment: The problem is text color, change it to `android:textColor="#000"` you will see the text appearing as you type.

Comment: No no no, the textbox itself works fine. It's VALUE (the programmatical value) does not change. As in, `input.getText()` returns null or blank.

Comment: Can you post the part of code, which you use textbox value.

Comment: ...and where you declare and instantiate the EditText too along with any other modifications you make to it's functionality like attaching a listener or invoking that Toast with a button press.

Comment: Added what I believe is necessary.

Comment: why you give  android:layout_width="0dp" ..

Comment: Two reasons: everywhere I've been, including my book, says do that when using weights. Second: it actually DOES distort/break if I set it to anything else. This isn't the question, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** be calling method `Convert` (which is responsible for retrieving edittext text as I could see from code) in `onClick` of a button. **(And not in `onCreate`)**

Then this should work fine.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.input.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The method itself was just in class space, and I'm calling it using XML `android:onClick="convert"`. It works fine. It's just that it comes up blank, or if I stick `android:text="2"` in the EditText, it comes up as 2 no matter what else I type.

Comment: @Ihasabone onclick of?

Comment: A button. Once again, you're giving me solutions for something that isn't broken or even the question.

Comment: @IHazABone I asked for info as you had not provided enough in question already. Wish you all the best. No idea about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`input.getEditableText()` returns an Editable object.

Use `input.getText().toString()` to return a String for the Toast to display.

More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: Oh gods, sorry, I accidentally left that in there. I was simply trying it. `input.getText()` yields the same (null) result.

Comment: Is it not `EditText.getText().toString()`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just didn't include that part by the sake of your answer.

Comment: Opps! I left the `toString()` part out. I've edited my answer.